# Custom control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть код своего контрола для Windows Form
Похож на прогресс бар.

```
 public partial class Slider : UserControl
    {
        public Slider()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.ForeColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
        }
        protected float percent = 0.0f;
        protected float maximumValue = 0.0f;
        public float Value
        {
            get
            {
                return percent;
            }
            set
            {

                if (value < 0) value = 0;
                //else if (value > 100) value = 0;
                percent = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        public float Maximum
        {
            get
            {
                return maximumValue;
            }
            set
            {
                maximumValue = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Brush br = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
            LinearGradientBrush lg = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height),Color.Cyan, Color.Blue, LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal);
            int width = (int)((percent / maximumValue) * this.Width);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, 0, 0, width, this.Height);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(lg, 0, 0, width, this.Height);
            br.Dispose();lg.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Делалась для видеоплеера, для отображения проигрывания видео.
Так вот хотел переделать под WPF но в WPF нет функции *OnPaint*.
Вычитал что в WPF аналогом есть метод *OnRender* но как именно сделать так и не понял. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать.

Answer (score 4):

Вы делаете неправильно. Контролы на WPF пишутся совсем не так, как на WinForms. Никакой `OnRender` вам не нужен, за вас должен всё делать layout manager.

Заведите себе `UserControl` через меню Visual Studio. У вас создадутся два файла: `Slider.xaml` и `Slider.xaml.cs`.

В `Slider.xaml` вам нужно разместить что-то вроде такого:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourApplicationNamespace.Slider"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*" Name="LeftColumn"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" Name="RightColumn"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column="0">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="1,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="Cyan" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

А в `Slider.xaml.cs` вы кладёте два стандартных DependencyProperty `Value` и `Maximum`, и устанавливаете колбек `UpdateValues` на их обновление:

```
public partial class Slider : UserControl
{
    public Slider()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region dp double Value
    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value", typeof(double), typeof(Slider),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0, (o, args) => ((Slider)o).UpdateValues()));
    #endregion

    #region dp double Maximum
    public double Maximum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(Slider),
            new PropertyMetadata(100.0, (o, args) => ((Slider)o).UpdateValues()));
    #endregion

    void UpdateValues()
    {
        var ratio = Maximum <= 0 ? 0.0 : Value / Maximum;
        if (ratio < 0)
            ratio = 0;
        if (ratio > 1)
            ratio = 1;
        LeftColumn.Width = new GridLength(ratio, GridUnitType.Star);
        RightColumn.Width = new GridLength(1 - ratio, GridUnitType.Star);
    }
}
```

Всё!

Пользоваться так:

```
<Window x:Class="YourApplicationNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApplicationNamespace"
        Title="Test" Height="100" Width="350">
    <Grid>
        <local:Slider Background="DarkGray" Value="80" Height="20"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Результат:

[image: выглядит стрёмно, чесгря]

Comment: Выглядит не нативно

Comment: @DmitrySokolov: Ну да, я сделал такой же вид как и у автора вопроса. Если вам нужен нативный слайдер, почему бы не взять слайдер из стандартной поставки?