# Перемещение слайдера по щелчку мышки. NaN число C#

Tags: c#, slider

Привет!

Есть самодельный слайдер для видео. 
Тема со [слайдером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587552/custom-control-wpf) 
Так вот, хочу сделать чтобы при щелчке по слайдеру перематывало на тот момент, который соответствует значению слайдера. 
**Вот код:**

```
        private void slider_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
           float percentTime = ( (float)e.GetPosition(slider).X / (float)slider.Width ) * 100;
           pos = (float)media.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds / 100 * percentTime;
           media.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)pos);
           text.Text = e.GetPosition(slider).X.ToString();
        }
```

С расчетами все нормально. Проблема в том, что крашится потому, что число NaN. 
Как видно в коде я выводил числа в TextBox для проверки и они нормальные, а не NaN. 
До нажатия имеют свои числовые типы. 
В NaN преобразуются именно при нажатии на слайдер.
Деления на ноль нету.
Первый раз с таким столкнулся и что делать не понятно.

Comment: Укажите язык программирования в метках вашего вопроса - так на ваш вопрос обратят гораздо больше внимания.

Comment: А чему равно `slider.Width`?

Comment: В xaml   сделал Width="Auto" при запуске  программы она равна 421 и потом меняется при растяжении или уменьшении окна также у него есть Margin  снизу  15 по бокам 48

Comment: Решилось вводом дополнительной переменной.
Запись ширины в нее и делением на эту переменную.но не закрашиваем  да текущего значения